# How to automate "Authentication required" pop up in Opera 12.x with Selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, webdriver, opera

I am trying to get opera to login to a local page that requires a username and password. I have tried the 2 different ways i know

```
private static String URL = "http://username:password@sample.com"; //works with Firefox and Chrome
```

-using the robot class, works with IE.

but now i am having trouble with getting selenium 2.43.1 to login to the page.

Comment: If you already have IE working with Robot, can't you modify that to work with Opera?

Answer (score 1):

If you are facing Basic authentication issues, try authenticateUsing() method.

The Alert Method, `authenticateUsing()` lets you bypass the **Http Basic Authentication** box.

> WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
>   Alert alert = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent());
>   alert.authenticateUsing(new UserAndPassword("**USERNAME**", "**PASSWORD**"));